# Codenameone: How to stop XFClient findAndWait request when network exception occurs so the calling thread can progress?

Tags: codenameone

My CN1 app uses XFClient to communicate with mySQL database on a server running Xataface.  The timer thread calls XFClient's findAndWait method and then sleeps 1 second before repeating. It works well 99+% of the time but sometimes the app encounters a network problem (Bad Gateway, ConnectionExceptions, SocketTimeOutException, etc.) and stops communicating with the server because findAndWait keeps waiting in spite of the exception.  Is there a way for findAndWait to stop waiting when an exception occurs?

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

1. comsume the error.  This suppresses the error message to the user
   but the findAndWait keeps waiting
2. Request.setTimeout(5000) to kick out after 5 secs (based on [SocketTimeoutException in CodeNameOne build on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548029/sockettimeoutexception-in-codenameone-build-on-android-device)) .  No effect.  The findAndWait keeps waiting.  Tried this at the NetworkManager and at the request level.
3. In handleException for NetworkManager, added code below
   (based on https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/733).  It compiled and ran but findAndWait kept waiting.

   ```
       NetworkManager.getInstance().addErrorListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               System.out.println("got a network error.  will kill the connect request and consume it.");
               if (theXFClient.getcRMP() != null) {
               NetworkManager.getInstance().killAndWait(theXFClient.getcRMP());
               }
               evt.consume();
           }
       });
   ```

I’m running this on the simulator, launching the app and then triggering the problem by disabling the network connection in the simulator menu.  I was hoping the timer thread would carry on when I turn back on the network connection but it is still stalled.

BTW - When the app is paused and resumed via the simulator menu (and real devices), the timer picks up right where it left off.  Hoping we can figure out a way that it can do that when network glitches happen as well.

Thx,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just added timeout and read timeout support that can be set on both the XFClient class and the XFQuery class.  If both XFClient and XFQuery for a particular query specify a timeout, then the XFQuery timeout will take precedent.

This update will be in Codename One settings soon, but you can download this new build directly right now from [here](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-xataface/tree/master/bin)

Comment: Thanks Steve for the quick reply.  The new code worked for me.  I used your timeout mods plus added setSilentRetryCount to XFClient so that each find and save will try a few times before popping up with the exception dialog.  BTW - I also added XFRecord.getUnixTime() because getDate() was reading mySQL datetime formatted column and converting to a date 1 month in the future.  Let me know if you want a copy.  Thx again, Mike

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  If you can make a pull request with those changes, I'll merge them.

Comment: Done.  Hope it's useful.  The XFClient readTimeout has improved resilience to network congestion although an interesting side-effect has arisen.  Occasionally the save is successful on the server but the readTimeout prevents the response code from arriving so the connection request retries.  Unfortunately that ends up attempting to create a duplicate record on a table that can't have duplicates.  Might increase the readTimeout from 2500 to something higher but with the extreme range of our user's network quality, it could be tough to find a solution that works for everyone.